Correct Counting of Independent Sets in a Complete Bipartite Graph $(K_{n, m})$
I'm diving into graph theory and am currently focused on understanding independent sets within complete bipartite graphs. Specifically, I've been pondering over how to accurately count the total number of independent sets in $(K_{n, m})$, where the graph is divided into two partitions containing $(n)$ and $(m)$ vertices, respectively. By definition, an independent set is a set of vertices no two of which are adjacent.
Given the nature of complete bipartite graphs, where vertices within the same partition are not adjacent to one another, it seems intuitive that any subset of a partition qualifies as an independent set.
My initial thought was to simply add the subsets of each partition together, subtracting one to avoid double-counting the empty set, which gives the formula $(2^n + 2^m - 1)$. This method accounts for the $(2^n)$ subsets that can be formed from the first partition and the $(2^m)$ subsets from the second, with the subtraction of one correcting for the empty set being counted in both.
However, I then considered that since subsets from one partition can be independently combined with subsets from the other, perhaps the multiplication principle applies, suggesting a total count of $(2^n \cdot 2^m = 2^{n+m})$. This interpretation would mean considering all possible combinations of subsets across the two partitions, including the empty set.
These two approaches yield vastly different results, leaving me uncertain about the correct way to count the total number of independent sets in a complete bipartite graph $(K_{n, m})$. Could someone help clarify the proper approach and its justification?

Your first line of reasoning is correct, your second incorrect. Any independent set of a complete bipartite graph $G$, is a subset of one side and one side only. If $S$ is a nonempty subset of the left side of the graph  and $T$ a nonempty subset of the right-side, then $S \cup T$ is not an independent set in the complete bipartite graph.
So what you got wrong in your second approach is this: you can't pick a subset $S$  of the left-side of $G$ (so $2^n$ choices for $S$) and then "independently" pick a subset $T$ of the right-side ($2^m$ choices for $T$), and say that  $S \cup T$ is an independent set of $G$, because it is not [unless at least one of $S$,$T$ empty that is].

would the maximal independent sets then be $((2^m - 1) + (2^n - 1))$?

No because then you would be double-counting the empty set twice. Excuse me, not counting the empty set at all.

It should instead be $(2^n-1)+(2^m-1)+1$.
